# How to make two animations at different times?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making an animation which should make a card move from one place to another by pressing the card. But I am having a problem. It is that I want ,that when it reaches the end of the animation, that the card is expanded in the style of a modal. But at the time of making the end of the animation, it is still the same size.

I can't find a way to do that type of animation. I tried two animations at the same time but they change in a very strange way.

This is my card:

```js
const abrir = e => {
    e.classList.add('diseñar')
}
```

```css
.card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0.4rem;
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 4px gray;
    transition: .3s;
}

.card:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.06);
}

.card-img {
    width: 50%;
}

.card-img>img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10.6rem;
    object-fit: fill;
}

.card-content{
    width: 50%;
    color: gray;
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: .7rem;
}

.content-date {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.card-content__botton {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.card-content__botton>button {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

.diseñar {
    animation: forwards 2s centrar;
}

@keyframes centrar {
    0% {
        margin: 0;
    }

    50% {
        margin-top: 300px;
    }

    100% {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-top: 300px;
        width: 950px;
        height: 10rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="card" id="1" onclick="abrir(this);">
    <div class="card-img">
        <img src="capablanca.jpg" alt="capablanca">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
        <div class="content-date">
            <div class="content-date__title">
                <span>Ganador de Torneo</span>
            </div>
            <div class="content-date__date">
                <span>26 de Octubre del 23</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content__content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis voluptatum quasi corrupti aliquam delectus perferendis et ea asperiores, neque quam alias aut totam aperiam quod accusantium mollitia, reprehenderit hic omnis.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove or adjust the height and width at 100% of keyframes.

Comment: I don't think it will be as simple as just CSS animation. You need to make that card absolute before animating it and it's not easy. [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375488/jquery-animate-from-relative-to-absolute-position-possible)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly -  the card should move to a new place - staying the same size while it moves, and then when it reaches the new place it expands? And when it expands it should do so over anything else, i.e. not disturb other elements' layout (like a modal).  Is that right?

Comment: @AHaworth yes, but apparently it is not possible to use only css

Comment: I can see a slightly odd way how to reserve space for where the card comes from so that nothing else moves, but now I'm not sure what you want when it expands - do you want the text to remain below the image? At the moment it is flexing it so the image and text are beside each other.

Comment: @AHaworth that's right, the image will be next to the text